# Get posts for which a custom field is not present, with get_posts

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, get-posts

I'd like to get all posts for which the custom field `hidden` is NOT present. This does not work:

```
$postsForSitemap = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'orderby' => 'modified', 
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page'), 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'meta_key' => 'hidden', 
    'meta_compare' => '!=')
);
```

because `meta_compare` is about the `meta_value`, not the key.

I haven't found in the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters how to get all posts that *don't have* a specific custom field.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` as the value for comparem, you could also check for empty value if thats relevant

This code only checks if `hidden` meta does not exists

```php
$postsForSitemap = get_posts([
    'numberposts'  => -1, 
    'orderby'      => 'modified', 
    'post_type'    => ['post', 'page'], 
    'order'        => 'DESC', 
    'meta_key'     => 'hidden', 
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
];
```

This checks is `hidden` meta does not exists OR has no value

```php
$postsForSitemap = get_posts([
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'orderby'     => 'modified', 
    'post_type'   => ['post', 'page'], 
    'order'       => 'DESC', 
    'meta_query'  => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key'     => 'hidden',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ],
        [
            'key'   => 'hidden',
            'value' => ''
        ]
    ]
];
```